# Message redelivery in Spring with JBOSS

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jms

I am using Spring SimpleMessageListenerConatiner where acknowledgement mode is 2 (client acknowledge) and Queue is Solace.

When I am throwing runtime exception from my unit test, means standalone spring config, messages are redelivering without any issue, but same code is not working when I am deploying my application in JBOSS.

public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

```
    try {
        throw new ConnectionException("Error in Connection");
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Throwing exception...");
        throw new MyRuntimeException("Throwing exception");
    } finally {
        LOGGER.info("Done...");
    }
}

Spring config is:
    <bean id="solaceMessageListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="solaceConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destinationName" value="QueueName"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="myListener"/>
        <property name="concurrency" value="1"/>
        <property name="destinationResolver" ref="destinationResolver" />
        <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="2"/>
    </bean>
```

Constaint:
1.  I cannot use DefaultMessageListenerContainer
2.  Session Transacted true is working but we have not to use it.

Comment: I got the issue. In my unit test I am using Spring 4 but in my application it is Spring 3. Redelivery of message, when throwing Runtime exception,  works in Spring 4 for Client acknowledgement mode. It could be JMS provider specific but working for Solace Q.